# How do I access File Manager and change to List View

Tags: filemanager

this is a daft question even to me - but I am new to Ubuntu so pls bear with me.

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 lts. Now Ubuntu is running and the most obvious way to explore my file system is the home button on the top left, but it shows icons instead of a list view.

Goggleing how to change it keeps talking about going to edit in the filemanager and change it - problem is there is no edit menu when i click that home button - and I am not even sure I am in the filemanager. So hence - how do I access the filemanager - or if I am in it - where is that damn edit menu so I can change to listview instead of that annoying icon view ?

Answer (score 6):

1. Click on the Home Folder

   [image]
2. Move you muse to the top bar of the screen, and click on view.  This top-panel is where the *global menu* exists - most applications have their menu's in this location.

   [image]
3. Click on List View to get what you want

   [image]

Comment: Excellent - that worked. Thanks a lot and sorry about the daft question.