# Missing compact view in Files

Tags: gnome, gui, filemanager

The Files application used to have 3 buttons for Icons, List and Compact view. I used to use the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> often to switch between them.

Now there are only two buttons for List and Icons, the preferences show only List and Icons as possible default views, and the menu doesn't show any of the options (visible on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/147460/129914)).

I think the change happened a few weeks ago, perhaps with an automatic update.

Is it normal?

Or do I need to fix something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Nautilus "real" compact mode in Ubuntu 13.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285461/how-to-get-nautilus-real-compact-mode-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but seems that compact view was removed on nautilus :-(
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2012-July/msg00005.html

I can't believe that, but it's a fact.

Comment: Anyone knows about some extension that would bring it back? Gnome 3 is all about being flexible and customizable, right?